# share CUDA library with docker container

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-12.04, docker

I am using docker to launch isolated apps. My app will use CUDA library for GPGPU computing. I am thinking of building an image with cuda installed on it but that would make it too huge. I am not sure either if CUDA display driver installation would go throuh successfully on docker image.

Better way would be to share CUDA libraries on the machine with the container, is there a way to do that ?

Thank you,
pradeep.

Comment: Are you sure that Docker provides for PCI-e pass through? Without it, there will be no way for your containerised app to interact with the host kernel driver or the GPU.

Comment: @talonmies: I am not sure about that either, i am new to docker also. So exploring ways to get CUDA running in a container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can mount your driver as a volume on your host, then you *might* be able to talk with it directly from within the container by mounting it with `docker run -v hostdir:containerdir:rw` (see [run docs](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/commandline/command/run/) )

If you don't have the device mounted outside the container, then I suspect that talking directly to your graphics card, even through shared libraries, will not work using a standard Docker configuration because the default LXC configuration in docker excludes `sys_rawio` for both security and portability reasons.

See the [lxc_template.go](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/v0.5.0/lxc_template.go#L97) file for the list of capabilities dropped by default.

Comment: thank you Andy. I do have the devices mounted, i just didn't know about the mounting part.

Comment: Ok, i got past most of the errors so far. Compilation of CUDA code also worked fine. I got a an executable generated, but when i run the thing, it spits out message that says incorrect NVIDIA driver version chosen. Will post the exact error message, i am trying something else now.

Comment: docker run -v /usr/bin:/usr/bin:ro -v /usr/lib:/usr/lib:ro -v /dev/dev:ro ubuntu nvidia-smi

NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidiactl: Operation not permitted

Comment: That means I might have been completely wrong about needing -v. Could you try it with `docker run --privileged`? That would give you the maximum container permissions. Let's see if that gets rid of the `Operation not permitted.` If that works, i'll re-do my original answer.

Comment: I cannot remember exactly, but I believe i did something related to enabling mknod (unfortunately i dont remember that either, it has been a long time since i moved away from docker and started working with lxc containers directly). I didn't had to use priviliged option, but the downside is i had to build docker from source.

mknod and other advanced system calls are most likely part of the priviliged mode that is available in recent versions of docker. So, i bet it would just work fine if we do `--privileged`

In any case, thanks a lot for helping out when i just started with containers :)

Answer (score 3):

I would start with just using

```
docker run --privileged ubuntu -ti --rm bash
```

the --privileged is a big hammer, but gives you a container that has full power :)